# Decoding htmlentities from database PHP

Tags: php, html-entities

I stored HTML to my database:

```
$ohtml = htmlentities($html);
```

But when I retrieve the data by using

```
$new_html = html_entity_decode($ohtml, ENT_QUOTES);
```

The data displayed is alright but I want to to be converted to real HTML not just display the codes. Ex. I want to display a textarea if the `$new_html = "<textarea> </textarea>";`

Comment: You just have your html string in your variable.  now render it.  use echo $new_html;

Comment: Don't mangle your data when storing it in a database, you'll regret it later. It is not needed for storing, there are other escaping mechanisms for that.

Comment: I have no idea but when I echo $new_html, it only shows plaintext like "<div id='form_field'> </div>" and not convert it to like, an HTML display.

Comment: Probably the entities still... entities. Look the source code and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo the `$new_html`.

```
$new_html = html_entity_decode($ohtml, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new_html;
```

**EDIT**: *Slow I am.. Trying to understand his question took so long others already posted comments with the solution...*

**EDIT2:** Try this code, it's working for me:

```
$html = "<b>I hate entities</b>";

$ohtml = htmlentities($html);

$new_html = html_entity_decode($ohtml, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new_html;
```

Comment: I have no idea but when I echo $new_html, it only shows plaintext like "<div id='form_field'> </div>" and not convert it to like, an HTML display

Comment: MelSyGallosa Look at my edited answer :) @RafaelBarros, true... But it felt like stealing someones solution :p

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already got it. It seems there was something wrong when I decoded it in the controller. It now seems fine.